# How to Install wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

Now i am working on rails 3.0.0.i am using Ubuntu 11.10 ,64 bit os.i want to install wkhtmltopdf.please tell me the static version of wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help installing static binary for wkhtmltopdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713004/help-installing-static-binary-for-wkhtmltopdf)

Comment: although the links sound good but i recommend you build wkhtmltopdf using source (it take time though) bcoz trying to install wkhtmltpdf using package result in no cookie support , page-break be save build it using source or you could just download the wicked_pdf gem which has a wkhtmltopdf binary with cookie patch and copy that binary in your /usr/local/bin If you want to save on time of compling and installing of wkhtmltopdf from source

Answer (score 15):

Installing `wkhtmltopdf`

on Ubuntu Linux machine

1. First check os is 32 bit or 64 bit by using following command

   Try `uname -m`. It seems like the `uname -m` actually gives x86_64 when it is an kernel 64 bits
2. Run following command

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openssl build-essential xorg libssl-dev libxrender-dev
   ```
3. Then run following command

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
   ```
4. Based on OS download wkhtmltopdf package from following site

   http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list

   OR

   ```
   wget http://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-i386.tar.bz2
   ```

   (wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-i386.tar.bz2 is a stable release for wkhtmltopdf )
5. Then extract using command

   ```
   tar xvjf wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-i386.tar.bz2
   ```
6. Then move extracted DIR to usr/local/bin folder

   ```
   sudo mv wkhtmltopdf-i386 /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
   ```
7. Check wkhtmltopdf is install or not using following command

   ```
   which wkhtmltopdf
   wkhtmltopdf –help
   ```

Installing wkhtmltopdf on MacOs

```
brew install Caskroom/cask/wkhtmltopdf
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to use official binaries within Rails is adding the following line to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-installer'
```

This way the official binaries from http://wkhtmltopdf.org will be downloaded and added to your bundle during `bundle install` phase.

Comment: This is the only option for gem that has the `0.12.x` versions

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem this morning.

Before you do anything, please check out: https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit/wiki/Installing-WKHTMLTOPDF

1. Download a binary edition of wkhtmltopdf at http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list
2. Decompress the package.
3. Copy the file like `wkhtmltopdf-i386` to `/usr/local/bin/` & `/opt/` (also you could make soft link).
4. That's done.

Good luck.