# wkhtmltopdf in Rails3 works on Mac, but failed on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, wkhtmltopdf

Error message:

```
command failed: /home/ubuntu/Circle/vendor/bin/wkhtmltopdf --encoding UTF-8 --print-media-type --page-size A4 --margin-top 0.8in --margin-right 0.5in --margin-bottom 0.8in --margin-left 0.5in --footer-font-size 10 --header-line --header-spacing 5 --footer-spacing 5 --header-right Powered\ by\ ctquan.com --footer-center \[page\] --header-center Elite\ English\ Circle --quiet - -
```

It works on Mac OSX, but fails on Linux of both development and production environment.

Comment: Take a look at the following: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11522746/529640 may help you in setting up on Ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for your help, man. I've solved the issue with a tricky method.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself with a tricky method.

Edit config/initializers/pdfkit.rb like this:

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltopdf = `which wkhtmltopdf`.gsub!(/\s/, '')
end
```

Anyway, it depends on a binary wkhtmltopdf, so add `gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'` in Gemfile. In this way, we will have a binary wkhtmltopdf in rvm. And `bundle install` will solve the problem of the dependency. There's no need to install an independent wkhtmltopdf instance.

So that Rails server can find wkhtmltopdf with the absolute path now, and everything works.

Comment: Or you could also set this in the initializers for your production and dev, pointing to the correct binary in each environment.

Comment: Yes, it's in the initializers folder.